# How can I rename files by switching the order of strings inside the filenames?

Tags: command-line, bash, rename, batch-rename

I think the title is not clear, English is not my first language, sorry. But I hope you get the point with an example. I have a lot of files like this :

*(Name of Composer) Title of song - Name of artist.ext*

The constants are the parenthesis and the hyphen.

I'd like to rename as *Name of artist - Title of song (Name of Composer).ext*

I checked the man of rename and examples here and elsewhere on the web but to no avail. Is it possible? Could some bash-guru help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest `mmv` (from the package of the same name) over any of the `rename` commands for this kind of thing:

```
$ mmv -n '(*) * - *.*' '#3 - #2 (#1).#4'
(Name of Composer) Title of song - Name of artist.ext -> Name of artist - Title of song (Name of Composer).ext
```

If you are restricted to using the Perl-based `rename`, then

```
$ rename -n 's/^\((.*?)\) (.*?) - (.*?)\.(.*)$/$3 - $2 ($1).$4/' *.*
rename((Name of Composer) Title of song - Name of artist.ext, Name of artist - Title of song (Name of Composer).ext)
```

In either case remove the `-n` once you are happy with the proposed transformations.

Comment: Sorry for the late reaction but many thanks, mmv is great.